# C++ Qt extern variables in classes, crashing error (SIGSEGV)

Tags: c++, qt, crash, extern, segmentation-fault

I've never used extern variables before and I'm not really that good at OOP yet so I might be doing something silly, but it might be a thread "collision" problem or something else.

In the server class, I have a playerData object pointer, playerDataManager, that gets initialized in the server constructor. In the packetReader header file, I added playerDataManager as an external variable outside the class. The packetReader class calls a function in the playerData class when a client connects to the server which should add the client's QTcpSocket* to the 'clients' QList, but it crashes here. If I put `clients.append(new QTcpSocket());` in the playerData constructor, it works fine though. Any idea why it crashes?

playerdata.h

```
#ifndef PLAYERDATA_H
#define PLAYERDATA_H

//includes

class playerData
{
public:
    playerData();
    void addPlayer(QTcpSocket* client, QByteArray username);
    QList<QTcpSocket*> clients;

private:
    QMap<QTcpSocket*, QByteArray> usernames;

};

#endif // PLAYERDATA_H
```

playerdata.cpp

```
#include "playerdata.h"

playerData::playerData()
{
    //if I put "clients.append(new QTcpSocket());" here, it works fine
}

void playerData::addPlayer(QTcpSocket *client, QByteArray username){
    clients.append(client); //crashes here
    usernames.insert(client, username);
}
```

packetreader.h

```
#ifndef PACKET_H
#define PACKET_H

//includes

extern playerData *playerDataManager;

class packetReader
{
public:
    packetReader();
    void processPacket(QByteArray id, QByteArray msg, QTcpSocket *client);

private:
    void processPacket_initialConnection(QByteArray msg, QTcpSocket *client);
    void processPacket_badPacket(QByteArray msg, QTcpSocket *client);

    playerData *playerDataManager;

};

#endif // PACKET_H
```

packetreader.cpp

```
#include "packetreader.h"

packetReader::packetReader()
{
}

void packetReader::processPacket(QByteArray id, QByteArray msg, QTcpSocket *client){
    if(id=="0003") processPacket_initialConnection(msg, client);
    else processPacket_badPacket(msg, client);
}

void packetReader::processPacket_initialConnection(QByteArray msg, QTcpSocket *client){
    playerDataManager->addPlayer(client, msg);
}

void packetReader::processPacket_badPacket(QByteArray msg, QTcpSocket *client){
    qDebug()<<"Bad packet"<<msg<<"received from"<<playerDataManager->getUsername(client);
}
```

server.h and server.cpp just set up a basic tcp server that calls the processPacket function with id = "0003" when a new client connects.

Comment: "I've never used extern variables before" - then don't start now using them, I don't see any valid reason to use them in C++/Qt (and they aren't OOP either). Use class members instead.

Comment: That's what I was doing before, but it just turns into a mess of "setPlayerDataManager" functions and it was harder to manage. Also I dont even know if the crashing problem has anything to do with using extern.

Comment: “mess” and “hard to manage” is what describes global variables best. Right now you have a member *and* an extern variable (in packet.h), which can easily to mix up (using the member when you think you’re using the global variable and vice-versa), so better remove one of them.